# Extra tabstop on VSCode snippet with choices

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a snippet that stops an "extra" time. it's been annoying me, so I'm hoping someone can help me clear it up here.

```
"pylint": {
    "prefix": "pylint",
    "body": "# pylint: ${1|disable,enable|}=${2|R0102\\, simplifiable-if-statement,R0101\\,too-many-nested-blocks|}",
    "description": "Add a pylint comment"
},
```

For some reason it stops on [`disable`, `enable`], then on `=` ?!, and then again (appropriately) on [`R0102, simplifiable-if-statement`, `R0101, too-many-nested-blocks`]. why is it stopping on the equals sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [a maintainer of the project](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39579#issuecomment-349692151), this is "as-designed".

> Choice elements are treated as regular (nested) snippets and we always jump to the end of snippet when it's "finished". That's why the cursor stops there. Unlikely that we will change this behaviour. Closing as designed

So, I tested it with this snippet:

```
"dummy": {
    "prefix": "dummy",
    "body": "# dummy: ${1|this,that|} - ${2|is,was|} - ${3|good,bad|}",
    "description": "a dummy snippet",
},
```

and indeed, it appears that tabstops stop before **and after** choice elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work:

Extension [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros#overview)

`settings.json`

```json
"macros": {
    "jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder": [
        "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder"
    ]
}
```

`keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "command": "macros.jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder",
    "key": "tab",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && hasNextTabstop && inSnippetMode && !editorTabMovesFocus && suggestWidgetVisible"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue [Remove tabstob in snippets after choice](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93740) is now a "Backlog Candidate" so go there and upvote it if you would like to see it changed.